# How can I download the image that I have uploaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, download

I have a page where there is an `asp:fileupload` then by the time a picture has been uploaded, it will be stored to an image folder. I also made another webpage which has a gridview  and that gets the images from the destination folder. However my problem is that I want to download the uploaded images when clicked. I have searched google but there is no answer to my query. Hope you can help me. Here is my code on the grid view part where it gets all of the uploaded images:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            binddepositslipgrid();

        }
    }
    public void binddepositslipgrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DepositID, Image from DepositSlip ", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select DepositID, Image from DepositSlip", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "data");
        gvDeposit.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        gvDeposit.DataBind();


    }
    protected void gvDeposit_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        int catid = int.Parse(gvDeposit.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        conn.Open();
        da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from DepositSlip where DepositID=" + catid, conn);
        da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        binddepositslipgrid();
    }
```

Comment: Because images's MIME type can be explained with IIS, so I think maybe you need to add the image file to a zip file,and download the zip file,of course ,these actions must be done automatically

Comment: how can i do that sir pls

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyNameTransfom : ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.INameTransform
    {

        #region INameTransform 成员

        public string TransformDirectory(string name)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public string TransformFile(string name)
        {
            return Path.GetFileName(name);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public partial class Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ZipFileByCode();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 压缩打包文件
        /// </summary>
        public void ZipFileByCode()
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] buffer = null;

            using (ZipFile file = ZipFile.Create(ms))
            {
                file.BeginUpdate();
                file.NameTransform = new MyNameTransfom();//通过这个名称格式化器，可以将里面的文件名进行一些处理。默认情况下，会自动根据文件的路径在zip中创建有关的文件夹。

                file.Add(Server.MapPath("/Content/images/img01.jpg"));
                file.Add(Server.MapPath("/Content/images/img02.jpg"));
                file.CommitUpdate();

                buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.zip");
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

you need to download the dll `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write handler for this operation and in `ProcessRequest()` method you write code for downloading file

//I have set the `ContentType` to `"application/octet-stream"` which cover any type of file

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

                    // context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=abc.jpg" + Path.GetFileName(file));
                    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

                    //context.Response.w(file);
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                    //you can also implement other business request such as delete the file after download
                    context.Response.End();
```

using above code you can download the image.

Comment: where will i write this sir @Kiran Bhagat?

Comment: you add one handler file in your project. this file allready contains ProcessRequest()

Comment: public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) like this

Comment: how can  i get the handlers? not able to search for a tutorial on this. im sorry im new. @Kiran Bhagat

Comment: right click on project and add new item select Generic Handler

Comment: thank you i have it now. how will i be able to click on the image and download it?

Comment: i have copied your code. how will it be linked on my aspx page that contains the image? and also, its not reading the "data" in your code.

Comment: add anchor tag outside your image tag and add handler url as href for that tag. and pass filename and file url as querystring

Comment: can you give me an example of the anchor tag pls?

Comment: <a href=""/Handler/Download.ashx?fileName=" + file.name + "&filePath=" + notice.fileUrl">img tag here</a>

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways to do it I have done by using link button in gridview. Here is my code.

```
   protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
            Int32 RowIndex = row.RowIndex;
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            dynamic di = new DirectoryInfo(FinalPath+"\\");
            dtable.Columns.Add("DownloadLink", typeof(string));
            dtable.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
            DataRow dr = null;
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
            {
                dr = dtable.NewRow();
                dr["FileName"] = fi.Name;
                dr["DownloadLink"] = FinalPath+"\\" + fi.Name;
                dtable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            int i = row.RowIndex;
            string filename = null;
            filename = dtable.Rows[i]["FileName"].ToString();
            string path__1 = (FinalPath + filename);
            string name = dtable.Rows[i]["FileName"] .ToString();
            string last = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('.'));
            string ext = last;
            string type = "";
            if (ext != null)
            {
                switch (ext.ToLower())
                {
                    case ".html":
                        {
                            type = "text/HTML";
                            break;
                        }

                    case ".txt":
                        {
                            type = "text/plain";
                            break;
                        }

                    case ".GIF":
                        {
                            type = "image/GIF";
                            break;
                        }

                    case ".pdf":
                        {
                            type = "Application/pdf";
                            break;
                        }

                    case ".doc":
                        {
                            type = "Application/doc";
                            break;
                        }
                    case ".rtf":
                        {
                            type = "Application/msword";
                            break; 
                        }

                    default:
                        {
                            type = "";
                            break; 
                        }

                }
            }
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
            {
                Response.ContentType = type;
            }
            Response.WriteFile(path__1);
            Response.End();
        }
        catch
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "myscript", "alert('Something Went Wrong!');", true);
            return;
        }
}
```

Image will download when you click on the link button. It will appear like this.

[image]